# RSpec argument match array of hashes

Tags: ruby, rspec, rspec3

I would like to use argument matchers provided by rspec to match an array of hashes. This is ideally the code I would like:

```
  context 'logging stock levels' do
    subject { double(:stock_logger, stock_updated: nil) }
    let(:stock_importer) { described_class.new(logger: subject) }
    before(:each) { stock_importer.import }

    it { is_expected.to have_received(:stock_updated)
                          .with(array_including(hash_including('sku', 'count_on_hand'))) }
  end
```

This errorred with an argument mismatch for me. The only working solution I can come up with is the following:

```
  context 'logging stock levels' do
    subject { double(:stock_logger, stock_updated: nil) }
    let(:stock_importer) { described_class.new(logger: subject) }
    before(:each) { stock_importer.import }

    it do
      is_expected.to have_received(:stock_updated) do |stock_levels|
        expect(stock_levels).to include(include('sku', 'count_on_hand'))
      end
    end
  end
```

Was I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

With Rspec 3.3, This worked for me:

```
expect(<Object>).to receive(:method).with(
  array_including(hash_including( {"id" => some_id} ))
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `array_including` but with the hash keys. Untested, but perhaps something like:

```
it do
  is_expected.to have_received(:stock_updated)
    .with(include(include("sku"), include("bar")))
end
```

Comment: I tried `array_including('sku' => a_kind_of(String), 'count_on_hand' => a_kind_of(String)))` but it didn't match. That wouldn't make sense if it worked anyways.

Comment: `expect([{:foo => "blah", :bar => "blah2"}]).to include(:foo => be_a_kind_of(String), :bar => be_a_kind_of(String))` just worked in the console for me

Comment: Yeah that's how I've currently solved it. I'd like to solve it with arg matcher syntax from rspec-mocks however.

Comment: I just don't understand why `array_including(hash_including('sku', 'count_on_hand'))` doesn't work when `hash_including(data: hash_including('a', 'b'))` does work.

Comment: oh I think I got it, this worked: `expect([{:foo => "blah", :bar => "blah2"}]).to include(include(:foo), include(:bar))` maybe not specifying array/hash will help? I'll modify the answer for you to try